# Header Component Stopped Showing When I Used useNavigate Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I've been following along this [video](https://youtu.be/N0dzlKamNfM) series on creating a special type of dropdown hamburger menu. When I got to [this part](https://youtu.be/N0dzlKamNfM?t=869) of the video I had to make some changes as I was using react router dom v6 and had learned the the `withRouter` had been deprecated.

Currently the menu is suppose to disappear once I click on the link to the new page. However after adding in the `useNavigate` hook my header has completely disappeared. I'm not 100% familiar yet with some of the hooks in react and have found myself stuck on getting my header to appear again and have the menu work. I have put the code I'm working with below, and really could use some guidance on how to get this to work without switching to v5 and going with the video tutorial.

`App.js`

```
import "./App.scss";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import MenuWrapper from "./components/MenuWrapper";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <MenuWrapper>
          <Header />
        </MenuWrapper>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="home">
              <Routes>
                <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
                <Route
                  exact
                  path="/opportunities"
                  element={<Opportunities />}
                />
                <Route exact path="/solutions" element={<Solutions />} />
                <Route exact path="/contact-us" element={<Contact />} />
              </Routes>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Opportunities() {
  return <p>Discover our numerous opportunities</p>;
}

function Solutions() {
  return <p>Solutions that help you.</p>;
}

function Contact() {
  return <p>Feel free to reach us.</p>;
}

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="wrapper">
        <h5>
          The <b>HAMBRG</b>, is a creative, engineer driven, global agency
          working on advancing the software, advertising and design communities
          to new heights.
        </h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

`MenuWrapper.jsx`

```
const withRouter = (Component) => {
  const MenuWrapper = (props) => {
    const history = useNavigate();

    return <Component history={history} {...props} />;
  };

  return MenuWrapper;
};
export default withRouter;
```

`Header.jsx`

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Hamburger from "./Hamburger";

const Header = () => {
  //State for menu button
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    initial: false,
    clicked: null,
    menuName: "Menu",
  });

  //State for disabled button
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  //Use effect for page changes
  useEffect((history) => {
    history.listen(() => {
      setState({ clicked: false, menuName: "Menu" });
    });
  });

  const handleMenu = () => {
    disableMenu();
    if (state.initial === false) {
      setState({
        initial: null,
        clicked: true,
        menuName: "Close",
      });
    } else if (state.clicked === true) {
      setState({
        clicked: !state.clicked,
        menuName: "Menu",
      });
    } else if (state.clicked === false) {
      setState({
        clicked: !state.clicked,
        menuName: "Close",
      });
    }
  };

  //Determine if our menu should be disabled
  const disableMenu = () => {
    setDisabled(!disabled);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setDisabled(false);
    }, 1200);
  };

  return (
    <header>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="wrapper">
          <div className="inner-header">
            <div className="logo">
              <Link to="/">HAMRG.</Link>
            </div>
            <div className="menu">
              <button disabled={disabled} onClick={handleMenu}>
                Menu
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Hamburger state={state} />
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

`Hamburger.jsx`

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Hamburger = ({ state }) => {
  let menu = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.clicked === false) {
      // close the menu
      menu.style.display = "none";
    } else if (
      state.clicked === true ||
      (state.clicked === true && state.initial === null)
    ) {
      // open the  menu
      menu.style.display = "block";
    }
  });

  return (
    <div ref={(el) => (menu = el)} className="hamburger-menu">
      <div className="menu-secondary-background-color"></div>
      <div className="menu-layer">
        <div className="menu-city-background"></div>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="menu-links">
              <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/opportunities">Opportunities</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/solutions">Solutions</Link>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <Link to="/contact-us">Contact Us</Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
              <div className="info">
                <h3>Our Promise</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
                  do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
                  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
                  irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
                  dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
                  cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt
                  mollit anim id est laborum.
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="locations">
                Location:
                <span>Dallas</span>
                <span>Austin</span>
                <span>New York</span>
                <span>San Francisco</span>
                <span>Beijing</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hamburger;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things here - you don't need the `withRouter` wrapper at all - all it's really doing is passing the `navigate` property to a wrapped element (but you're not actually using it). If you need a `navigate` in the wrapped element, you can just use the hook -

```
const Header = () => {
    // If you need 'navigate', just use the hook
    const navigate = useNavigate();
};
```

Now, looking at the [final code from the tutorial](https://github.com/wrongakram/react-hamburger-menu/blob/master/src/components/Header.js), it looks like the `history` was only being used to listen to page changes; you could do the same thing with [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#uselocation) -

```
const Header = () => {
  // ----- 8< -----
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    setState({ clicked: false, menuName: "Menu" });
  }, [location]);
};
```

You've also got a bug (potentially?) in the effect in `Hamburger.js`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (state.clicked === false) {
      // close the menu
      menu.style.display = "none";
    } else if (
      state.clicked === true ||
      (state.clicked === true && state.initial === null)
    ) {
      // open the menu
      menu.style.display = "block";
    }
});
```

The `else if` here is incorrect. If `state.clicked === true` then the `if` will short circuit; if `state.click === false` then neither the left side nor the right side will evaluate to `true`; so in other words, you're just checking:

```
if (state.clicked === true) {
}
```

Which might be what you want, or it might be a bug ‍♀️

Comment: Heya Gerrod, 

Thanks so much for the help on this. I really appreciate your detailed breakdown and insight as it has also given me something to make reference to in future projects.

Comment: Also are you saying there is no need to use navigate and if I should still be using it where should I be plugging in the `navigate` const?

Comment: Yes correct - you only need to `useNavigate()` if you want to programatically change the URL - https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate